# Can't receive push notification iOS

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have 3 token: Token1, Token2, Token3
Token1 push notification OK

Token2 push notification NOT OK

Token3 push notification OK

Token3 is my device

If I push to Token1, Token3 => OK. I received message.

If I push to Token2, Toten3 => NG. I can't received message.

I'm using PHP to push notification:

```
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

foreach ($token_devices as $token_device) {
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $token_device->token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
}

fclose($fp);
```

Now I need push to Token2, Token3 => My device is Token3 can receive message.
Please help!!!!

Comment: There is quite a bit of work that goes into sending push notifications that I can't verify from this question. Do you have a sandbox APS certificate on your PHP server and is it being properly passed to the APS server. Are you using the sandbox server URL? Is your device token current and/or set up properly? Are you trying to send push notifications to the simulator? Because you can't do that.

Comment: Hi. I'm pushing to sandbox (ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195).
My device is ipod. I think I haven't got problem with my token & device.
Token1, Token3 => is valid token.
Token2 is invalid token.
If I push to Token2 then push to Token3 => My device (token3) can't receive it.
I I push to Token1 then push to Token3 => My device receive it.
I don't now why I push to invalid token then push to valid token. My device (valid token) can't receive message

Comment: So what about a certificate with APS sandbox capabilities?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.
I'm using develop Pem, not distribution pem.

Comment: Did you create the certificate?

Comment: Member of my team created it.